# White-space nowrap losing the elements width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a grid with resizable boxes. It would be nice to have a scrollbar for the `x` axis if needed. The problem is if I have a nested list:

```
<ul>
    <li>blubb 1</li>
    <li>blubb 2
        <ul>
            <li>blubb 1</li>
            <li>blubb 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the surrounding element has a smaller width the list kind of collapses.

What I'm trying to find out is:

- why ?
- is there a way to stop this from happening?
- is there a way to get a `padding-right` around the list (or all other html elements) so no content is sticking at the right side with the green border?

Obviously if the surrounding `<div>` has a big enough `width` it works as expected. So the red border goes around all content and this is what I want. **BUT** depending on the content and not on the wrapper. Cause the wrapper is resizable (in the real life scenario) and can change it's width all the time.

```css
.no-wrap *:not(p) {
     white-space: nowrap;
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300px;
}

.flex-box .col {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0.2;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flex-box .col:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0.7;
}

.col ul {
    border:solid 1px orange;
    display: block;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.col > ul {
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
    <div class="col no-wrap">
      <h4>Why is red<br>border not<br>surrounding<br>all ul li(s)</h4>
      <ul>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant
              <ul>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant
                      <ul>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant
                              <ul>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="col no-wrap">
      <h4>Just like here</h4>
      <ul>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant
              <ul>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                  <li>Pellentesque habitant
                      <ul>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                          <li>Pellentesque habitant
                              <ul>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                                  <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
          <li>Pellentesque habitant</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[For JsFiddle click here](https://jsfiddle.net/hvs5Lzgz/1/)

Comment: `.col ul {
    min-width: 300px;
}`  add at the end,  similar things may work

Comment: @bhv yes they do work, but then if content is less then 300px I get a scrollbar which I don't want. In short, setting fixed withs is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

you can add overflow:auto to you ul, that way all you list wont overflow to their parent but will add a scroll bar.

[image]

```
.col ul{
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: But I need `display: flex;` for the resizable grid

Comment: Please read the question: `Obviously if the surrounding <div> has a big enough width it works as expected`

Comment: @caramba I've updated my answer not sure if it's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. But no, I then rather stick with what I've got